# angular ng-repeat isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a button on ng-repeated items which when clicked should change the url and also change the state of the current item on which the button was clicked. I have a ui-sref which is binded to this button and a custom directive on the ng-repeat element whcih is suppose to create a scope for the current item on which the button was clicked. This is the code...

```
<div open-prices open="ui-sref" data-ng-repeat="thing in things">
```

Code for the button is...

```
<a ui-sref=".prices({priceId:price._id})" type="button"> Click</a>
```

Code for the custom directive is....

```
app.directive('openPrices', [
function() {
    return {

        restrict: 'A',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

        },

        scope: {
            open:'='
        }
    };
} ]);
```

My problem is when the button is clicked, the state of all the repeated items changes but I want the state of the current item whose button is clicked to change state.